# What is the way to create DataFrame of length of intersections of a list of sets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary filled with sets. It might look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'gs_1': set(('ENS1', 'ENS2', 'ENS3')), 
           'gs_2': set(('ENS1', 'ENS4', 'ENS5', 'ENS7', 'ENS8')),
           'gs_3': set(('ENS2', 'ENS3', 'ENS6'))}
```

I've also built a pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=my_dict.keys())
my_df.gs_1=[0, 0, 0]
my_df.gs_2=[0, 0, 0]
my_df.gs_3=[0, 0, 0]
my_df.index = my_dict.keys()

my_df
```

Yields

```
      gs_1  gs_2  gs_3
gs_1     0     0     0
gs_2     0     0     0
gs_3     0     0     0
```

My goal here is to populate the DataFrame with the length of the intersection between each set as efficiently as possible. The DataFrame doesn't strictly have to be built before-hand and then populated. Right now, my working solution is:

```
for gs_1 in my_df.index:
    for gs_2 in my_df.columns:
        my_df.loc[gs_1, gs_2] = len(my_dict[gs_1] & my_dict[gs_2])

my_df
```

Yields, correctly,

```
      gs_1  gs_2  gs_3
gs_1     3     1     2
gs_2     1     5     0
gs_3     2     0     3
```

My problem is that this is far too slow. In practice, gs_n extends to around 6000, and my projected runtime for this approaches 2 hours. What's the best way to go here?

Comment: You could try scipy's [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and pass in set difference length as a custom distance metric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my approach based on `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`:

```
# create unions of values
total = set()
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    total = total.union(val)

total = list(total)

# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({}, index=total)

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    df[key] = pd.Series(np.ones(len(val)), index=list(val))

df = df.fillna(0).astype(bool)

# return result:
x = df.values
np.sum(x[:,np.newaxis,:]&x[:,:,np.newaxis], axis=0)

#array([[3, 1, 2],
#       [1, 5, 0],
#       [2, 0, 3]], dtype=int32)

# if you want a data frame:
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.sum(x[:,np.newaxis,:]&x[:,:,np.newaxis],
                             axis=0),
                     index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
```

Took 11s for 6000 `gs_` and 100 unique values:

```
max_total = 100
my_dict = {}

for i in range(6000):
    np.random.seed(i)
    sample_size = np.random.randint(1,max_total)
    my_dict[i] = np.random.choice(np.arange(max_total), replace=False, size=sample_size)
```

---

Edit: if you have a large number of unique values, you can work on small subsets, and add them up. Something like:

```
chunk_size = 100
ans = np.zeros(num_gs, num_gs)
for x in range(0, len(total), chunk_size):
    chunk = total[x:x+chunk_size]
    df = pd.DataFrame({}, index=chunk)

    for key, val in my_dict.items():
        sub_set = val.intersection(set(chunk))
        df[key] = pd.Series(np.ones(len(sub_set )), index=list(sub_set ))

    df = df.fillna(0).astype(bool)

    # return result:
    x = df.values

    ans += np.sum(x[:,np.newaxis,:]&x[:,:,np.newaxis], axis=0)
```

With 14000 unique values, that would that approximately 140 * 15 = 2000 seconds. Not so fast but significantly less than 2 hours :-).

You can also increase `chunk_size` if your memory allows. That was the limit of my 8GB Ram system :-).

Also, it is possible to parallelize on the subsets (`chunk`) as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with np.newaxis; would replacing that with 'None' change anything?

Comment: It's an alias for `None`: `print(np.newaxis is None)`.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it works for the specifications in the question. In practice, it turns out that each set is between 10 and 1000 unique values, and there are ~14000 unique values in total that fill all the sets. Running this solution becomes memory-prohibitive; it was reaching around ~200GB memory usage before I decided to kill it. Do you have any suggestions to accommodate this?

Comment: Wow, you have a system with more than 200GB memory. See edited answer for an approach to big data problem.

Comment: I was hopeful for the chunking solution to work, but I still ran into the same memory problem. I ended up putting more thought into this and found a solution that I think works better (I've posted it below). Thanks for all the help, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Quang's solution worked well, but it broke down when I tried to put it into practice; even with the chunking solution, I ran into memory issues at the last step:

```
    ans += np.sum(x[:,np.newaxis,:]&x[:,:,np.newaxis], axis=0)
```

I decided to take an alternative approach, and I managed to find a solution that was both faster and more memory-efficient when applied to the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np 
my_dict = {'gs_1': set(('ENS1', 'ENS2', 'ENS3')), 
           'gs_2': set(('ENS1', 'ENS4', 'ENS5', 'ENS7', 'ENS8')),
           'gs_3': set(('ENS2', 'ENS3', 'ENS6'))}

gs_series = pd.Series({a:b for a,b in zip(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(my_dict.keys(),2),
                      [len(c&d) for c,d in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(my_dict.values(),2)])})

gs_df = gs_series.unstack()
proper_index = gs_series.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
gs_df = gs_df.reindex(proper_index)[proper_index.values].copy()

i_lower = np.tril_indices(np.array(len(gs_df.columns)), -1)
gs_matrix = gs_df.values
gs_matrix[i_lower] = gs_matrix.T[i_lower]
gs_df
```

This yields, correctly,

```
      gs_1  gs_2  gs_3
gs_1   3.0   1.0   2.0
gs_2   1.0   5.0   0.0
gs_3   2.0   0.0   3.0
```

The basic idea was to build a dictionary with the length of the intersection between each 2 sets using `itertools`, and convert that to a `pd.Series`. `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` performs each comparison once, so upon unstacking of the `pd.Series`, we have the (unordered) top right triangle of the matrix. Sorting the rows and the columns by our original index leaves us with a correctly populated top right triangle, and all that's left to do is reflect that onto the bottom left triangle of the matrix. I wound up using ~8 GB of RAM for a 5200x5200 matrix comparison, where there are ~17000 possible unique values to fill in each set and each set contains 10-1000 unique values. This finished in a matter of minutes.